# How to get a "not clear what you're asking" question unheld after edit

Tags: support

So, I worked out what the asker of this question actually wanted:

[How do you invoke an if statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50138699/how-do-you-invoke-an-if-statement)

I've since editted the question to make it more clear and have an answer that I would like to provide but I cannot because the question has since been closed.

How Can I fix this?

Comment: Nothing. Once your edit goes through, the question will be sent to the "reopen" queue. People there will review if they think it's worth reopening or not. (basically: nothing more, you've done your part)

Comment: And above all, pushed back onto SO user's Interesting page.  If it didn't get interesting, a common flaw, then it is unlikely to get reopened.  The act of attempting to fix a question by removing the word "inside" from the question text is better known as "turd polishing".  If you think the question is interesting then just ask it yourself.

Comment: I've seen a lot worse questions, it has to said.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to wait, and keep an eye on the post. Consider favoriting the question, to make it easier for you to find again.

A couple things will need to happen:

First, your edit needs to be accepted. Right now, it's still pending in the queue. Shouldn't take it too long to get reviewed, especially if users that see your post here bother to review it.

Second, the post will go through the reopen queue. There, users will decide if it's not clear enough to reopen or not. This process may also be sped up by your question here, but not necessarily.

Once that happens, you'll be free to post your answer. But there's really nothing more for your to do here. After your first edit, no other edits will put the post back in the reopen queue if it clears it as "Leave Closed." So, be patient, and check back on the post in a bit.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know whether or not the edit alone was enough to push it to the reopen queue or if I needed to contact a mod or flag it or something

Comment: The first edit after a post is closed will put it in the queue, IIRC. So, you've done all you can at this point. Good luck!

Comment: Cheers, I just really want to help this guy because I struggled with the whole main thread only GUI thing myself for a while